# Javascript parses in some way the string parameters of functions?

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, function

When I try to pass a string to a function like so

```
i="file:///bla/bla/bla";
Fade(i);
```

i get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

so i tried passing a literal in the function like `f("img1.jpg");`
and i got

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: img1 is not defined
(anonymous function)
```

What is going on?

(note that i am kind of new in js)

In particular:

```
timeout = 3;
var fadetime = 5;
var curr = 0;

var fadedelta = 100/(fadetime*30);
var opac = 100;

//var fadedelta = 100/(fadetime*3);
//prelaod all images just to have them there
var namearr = new Array( "img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", "img3.jpg", "img4.jpg");
var imgarr = new Array();

var i = 0;
for( i = 0; i<2 ; i++)
{
    var tmp = new Image()
    tmp.src = namearr[i];
    imgarr.push(tmp); 
}

function setOpacity(image, op)
{
    if(typeof(image.filters) != 'undefined' )
    {
        image.filters.alpha.opacity = op;
    }
    else
    {
        image.style.opacity = op/100;
    }
}

function fadeIn(isrc)
{
    var locimg = document.getElementById("image");
    opac -=fadedelta;
    setOpacity(locimg,opac);
    if(opac>0)
    {
        setTimeout("fadeIn(String("+isrc+"));", 30);
    }
    else
    {
        locimg.src = isrc;
        setOpacity(locimg,100);
        opac=100;
    }
}


function Fade(isrc)
{
    var locimg = document.getElementById("image");
    var locdiv = document.getElementById("imageArea");

    locdiv.style.backgroundImage = "url("+isrc+")";
    fadeIn(isrc);
}

function aStatus()
{
    var locimg = document.getElementById("image");
    var locdiv = document.getElementById("imageArea");

    alert("background: "+locdiv.style.backgroundImage+"\nforeground: "+locimg.src+"\ncurr: "+curr);
}

function onClick()
{
    curr = curr + 1;
    curr%=imgarr.length;
    Fade(String(""+imgarr[curr].src));
}
```

and the output is the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` error refering to the line before the last (`Fade(String(imgarr[curr].src));`)

note that imgarr[curr].src is file:///home/fakedrake/webdev/img1.jpg or file:///home/fakedrake/webdev/img2.jpg depending  on the value of curr

Comment: Could you post the block of code you are working with, including the `f` function?

Comment: ok here is the entire script http://pastebin.com/JByxfBiZ

Comment: yes it is because i only had two images in the directory and i was going to deal with that once i had some working code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a totally different error, about a “missing ) after argument list” on line

```
fadeIn(file:///some/local/file.jpg);
```

However, the problem is the same: the interpreter thinks that `fadeIn` gets a variable name (in this case `file:///some/local/file.jpg`, which is not a valid identifier) instead of a string.

The solution is simple: add single quotes to

```
setTimeout("fadeIn('"+isrc+"')", 30);
    // here        ^        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have a String that isn't terminate properly before the code you are showing.

```
var str = "test
// ...
i="file:///bla/bla/bla";
f(i);
```

The highlight of the code speaks for itself. When it reaches the `:`, it pops out the error since the synthax is invalid.

Comment: sorry about the messy post, i used the name f as a general case to demonstrate the problem as i faced it again and found a way around it (but not this time).

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit curious about this line:

```
fadeIn(isrc);
```

I'm not sure what that function does, but how do you fade in a string?

Isn't it acually one of the elements that you want to fade in?

```
fadeIn(locdiv);
```

#### Edit:

Seeing the code of the `fadeIn` function, I see that it should actually get a string. But it's the code in the function that is causing the string to be evaluated as code.

When you call `setTimeout` with a string, that string will be evaluated as code, and you are putting the parameter in the string without encoding it correctly. You could fix that, but the best is to not use a string in the `setTimeout` call at all:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ fadeIn(isrc); }, 30);
```

Comment: no what the fadeIn func does is fade make the "image" img fade and in its place to show the image with the url isrc. I dont think that functions do is not very relevant with the problem, only that js treats tha contents of imgarr[curr].src as code and not as a string object

Comment: ok the entire code is there... again sorry about the fuss, i thought it was trivial... also the String() is there in an attempt to solve the problem but it was a weak one...

Comment: @fakedrake: Well, actually what the function does proved to be very relevant to the problem. :) It's when the function calls itself that the error occurs, not in the initial call.